# setting the default value for insert parameters in sql datasource asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

i have a datasource, which has an insertparameters, one of which whose type is set to Boolean, but while adding it from code behind insertparameters.defaultvalue always return string.

code behind code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "InsertNew")
{
    TextBox Title = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddTitle") as TextBox;
    TextBox Quote = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddQuote") as TextBox;
    TextBox QuoteLink = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddQuoteLink") as TextBox;
    CheckBox Published = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkAddBox") as CheckBox;
    TextBox PublishedDate = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddPublishedDate") as TextBox;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Title"].DefaultValue = Title.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Quote"].DefaultValue = Quote.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["QuoteLink"].DefaultValue = QuoteLink.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Published"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(Published.Checked);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["PublishedDate"].DefaultValue = PublishedDate.Text;
     SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

and aspx code for sql datasource is:

```
<InsertParameters>  
    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />  
    <asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" />  
    <asp:Parameter Name="QuoteLink" Type="String" />  
    <asp:Parameter Name="Published" Type="Boolean" />  
    <asp:Parameter Name="PublishedDate" Type="DateTime" />  
</InsertParameters>
```

Please reply how should i set the datatype as boolean from code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Not sure why you are setting DefaultValue instead of the value

Or

2: Can you try this:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Published"].DefaultValue = Published.Checked==true?"true":"false";
```